# Is there a way to create a region of interest (ROI) on image using IDL?

Tags: image-processing, idl, roi

I am trying to analyze images using IDL, and I need to create an ROI. Specifically, I have hundreds of images, each containing 6 bands. Two of the bands contain the longitude and latitude information of each image. I want to create an ROI using set thresholds on latitude band. ENVI has a tool for creating ROIs using band thresholds but I don't have license for it. Is it possible to do it using IDL?

Thank you!

Comment: [Shane Andrews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11007437) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65161884) saying "This should help you to find out. I belive chapter 8 https://dav.lbl.gov/archive/NERSC/Software/idl/help6.1/image.pdf"

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Scratte. I will see if it is relevant for my case.

Comment: Note that I didn't find it. It was in your post as an Answer, but it was removed since it only contained a link.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @shaneandrews.